# Snort rule for detecting DNS packets of type NULL

Tags: domain-name-system, snort, ids

I am trying to detect DNS requests of type `NULL` using Snort. I located the type field of the request packet using Wireshark:

[image: dns NULL type]

I found the following rule on [McAfee](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/87616?start=0&tstart=0):

```
alert udp any any -> any 53 (msg:"NULL request"; content:"|01 00|"; offset:2; within :4; content:"|00 00 0a 00 01|"; offset:12; within:255; threshold: type threshold, track by_src, count 10, seconds 5; sid: 5700001; rev: 1)
```

However, first of all this rule does not work for me as it throws the following error message:

```
ERROR: /etc/snort/rules/local.rules(7) within can't be used with itself, protected, offset, or depth
```

Which is odd, because apparently using `within` in combination with `itself`, `protected`, ... wasn't a problem for McAfee. I am using Snort version `2.9.9.0`.

Furthermore, I also hoped that there would be a better way to address the `type` field of the DNS request. Instead of using a fixed offset to specify where in the packet you are looking for a specific pattern. Isn't there a way to look for the `Type` field in the `Queries` field of the `Domain Name System` section. This would also make the rule a lot more readable than using offsets and hexcode patterns.

So, my question is: Does anyone know a Snort rule that detects DNS requests of type `NULL`?

Comment: Filtering DNS traffic on a TCP/IP level is difficult because elements of the message are not at a fixed position in the packet. This resources (using iptables u32 extension) may help: http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html , https://github.com/dowjames/generate-netfilter-u32-dns-rule.py , https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html